# Deleting an unmanaged object from Finalize throws an AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, c++-cli

I'm writing a wrapper library using C++/CLI for an unmanaged C++ project. The goal is to expose this library to C# applications. Here's what I have so far.

```
#pragma once

#include "Settings.h"
#include "Settings/SettingsPrivate.h"

public ref class Settings
{
public:
    Settings();
    virtual ~Settings();

protected:
    !Settings();

public:
    unsigned char GetModel(int iNumber);


private:
    CSettings* m_pSettings;
};
```

---

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Managed/Settings.h"

Settings::Settings()
{
    // Pointer to unmanaged object
    m_pSettings = new CSettings();
}

Settings::~Settings()
{
    this->!Settings();
}

Settings::!Settings()
{
    if (m_pSettings)
    {
        delete m_pSettings;
        m_pSettings = NULL;         
    }
}

unsigned char Settings::GetModel(int iNumber)
{
    return m_pSettingss->GetModel(iNumber);
}
```

The code executes fine in the test application I wrote. The function call succeeds. The problem is that when the GC Finalizes this object, it throws an exception.

An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in Wrapper.dll

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

I can't see any obvious reason why this exception is being thrown. I tried disposing of the object explicitly by calling Dispose from my C# application. It still throws the same exception.

Here's the test application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WrapperTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Settings settings = new Settings();
            byte b = settings.GetModel(0);

            settings.Dispose();

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Would someone point out what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: No repro, don't see the problem. I assume the problem is in SettingsPrivate, heap corruption I would guess.

Comment: If you enable breaking on first chance AV in the debugger ("Debug -> Exceptions -> Win32 Exceptions -> Access Violation"; you may want to disable "just my code" in "Tools -> Options -> Debugging"), what is being accessed (you'll also need to enable native debugging in the C# project since I assume you're launching with it)?  Nothing is leaping out at me as being wrong from this snippet.

Comment: @Hans: Your comment last night put me on the right track to solving my problem. If you post an answer I'll give you the credit for this question.

Comment: Go ahead, post your answer to show what was really going on and mark it as the answer.  Everybody writing unmanaged code can learn something from debugging heap corruption problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a project configuration error. The code actually ran fine in Release mode.

In debug mode I linked in some release DLL's when I should have been statically linking against debug libraries. Why this caused memory corruption I haven't yet investigated but it has solved the problem.

Otherwise the code posted above is correct.

Comment: This reminded me later of DLLMain issue's.  You must not pre-empt the runtime (i.e. do not have code running before the CLR get's bootstrapped).

Answer (score 1):

You should enable more verbose heap debugging functionality.  I tested your code and it did not fail for me.  I had to use malloc/free instead of new/delete as you didnt define CSettings, however the effect should be the same.

I added this to make sure I had enough heap churn to trigger a failure if their was any corruption;

```
unsigned char Settings::GetModel(int iNumber)
{   
    for(int i=0; i < iNumber; i++)
        free(malloc(1024));
    return iNumber;
}
```

For me your code worked with no failure.  You should look into some of your compilation settings, are you linking to an external library for CSettings?  If so you need to make sure the CRT is the same version, etc.  Also you know you have to use one of the DLL run time's not /MT or /MTd.